# Google Maps v3 Windows Touch Devices Draggable Disabled

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with a full screen Google Map (v3) that is really just for display purposes rather than interaction (still want to make use of the API though so not just a static image) - so 100% screen width. I've disabled dragging and the scrollwheel and for the most part this is fine. However, I've found on Windows 8 tablets and smartphones that, although you can't interact with the map, you also can't touch the map and move the page down like you can on Android/iOS.

Here are the map options I'm using.

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 6,
  maxZoom: 6,
  minZoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng("-41.00477527259105", "172.891846078125"),
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  scrollwheel: false,
  draggable: false,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControl: false
};
```

I was able to come up with a CSS solution to place a transparent layer over top of the map which "resolves" the problem but I'd rather there was a nice solution built into the API that someone could recommend.

Here is the CSS solution I'm currently using if it is of any assistance:

```
.googlemap-box > div:before {
    background-color: transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: If all you need is a map for display purposes and no interaction, you can try out the Google [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). It will return the map as an image.

Comment: Thanks - yep I know about the static images which do have their place. It is still nice to be able to use the API and interact with the map via my own controls - or display custom markers, designed map colours, etc...

Comment: For what it's worth, markers and styling options are also possible in static maps. I do understand you may need more control over the map, though. I think the part where you said "although you can't interact with the map, you also can't touch the map and move the page down like you can on Android/iOS" needs some clarification.

Comment: Yep fair comment - I've amended my question to make this more clearer.